# Quearing unpredictable JSON objects from Elasticsearch using Springboot

Tags: json, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data

I am creating a spring-boot application which will interact with elasticsearch using spring-data. But the problem is, my data in the elasticsearch is unpredictable. That means there can be slight changes in the fields like additional fields or can be totally new field coming in JSON. Please guide me for a solution to address that. Using normal repository is seems not working because I don't have a defined JSON format. Your guide will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a bit more data on your case.

Normally, when you use `@Field` annotations, or introducing/dropping a new simple or object field, this should not be a problem at all since spring-data-elasticsearch updates mapping when you save to `ElasticsearchRepository`. In some cases, e.g. introducing a parent-child rel, you would need to drop and recreate index but this can also be done programatically, if needed.

If you need advanced mapping that is also changing dynamically, then you need to build and execute a mapping update request from your code on save (custom repo).